# Clear local notification from lock screen in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to only have one local iOS notification on my lock screen at any given time.

Calling `cancelLocalNotification` on a specific notification seems like a clunky way to do it (and is deprecated in iOS10). Is there any way to delete all notifications before pushing a new local repeating notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the `UIApplication` method - `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.
It is deprecated in iOS 10 because iOS 10 has the new `UNNotification` class.
If you use those - you could use the `UNUserNotificationCenter` method `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests` and also `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` to remove the notifications already delivered.

Comment: When is the appropriate time to call this though? There's no delegate option for when a UNNotification is about to be sent.

Comment: @arooo I suppose the best time would be just before presenting a new notification, based on what you've written about your use case.

Comment: Oh, for iOS 10 when using `UINotification` - also use `UINotificationCenter. removeAllDeliveredNotifications ` to remove all notifications already delivered.